# What are package contents and lightning components in reference to salesforce apps?

Tags: appexchange

I was wondering what package contents and lightning components are when they are being reference for salesforce apps on the AppExchange.

When I look up apps on the AppExchange I notice under the package contents and lightning components there are some breakdown of information such as custom objects for package contents or global for lighting components with a number which I assumed is the amount. What are these package components and lighting components referencing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global Lightning Components are those you can use directly in your own component markup. This should be the sum of all `access="global"` Aura Components and all LWC Components, which I believe are always "global," as far as I've ever been able to tell.

App Builder Components are those that are configured to appear in Lightning App Builder. These components are Aura Components that additionally define use an interface that makes it eligible for App Builder use (e.g. `flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes`), as well as LWC where `isExposed` is set to true, and has at least one target (e.g. `lightning__RecordPage`) that relates to App Builder.

Community Builder Components are those that are configured to appear in a Digital Experience. This includes Aura components that include interfaces such as `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes`, and LWC Components that have `isExposed` set to true, and at least one target that allows it to be used as such (e.g. `lightningCommunity__Page`).

In your example summary, note that there are not a total of 16 components in the package; there are only seven, all of which can be added in the App Builder, and only two in the Digital Experience Builder. The "global value" will be at least as big as either of the other two numbers. The summary tells you more information about what kind of functionality the package provides.

Answer (score 0):

Those are literally the components of the package.

As in, "this package contains 9 custom objects, 1 custom app (for the app launcher part of Salesforce's interface), etc... and by installing this app, these things will be added to your org".

Comment: yeah I figured that with at least package components but wasn't sure, I was actually trying to figure out what are the information under lighting components are. Is globals referencing global variables or global components? And so what are they? same thing for app builder and community builder , trying to understand what are the actual breakdowns for these terms.